# Recursively reverse a list python throws error

Tags: python-3.x, string, recursion, reverse

I want to understand why code 1 is throwing the below error
"AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'"

1. ```
   def reverse(s):
       if len(s) == 1:
           return list(s)
       else:
           return reverse(s[1:]).append(s[0])
   ```

the same logic works if "s" is a string

2

```
s="hello"
def reverse(s): 
    if len(s) == 1: 
        return s 
    else: 
        return reverse(s[1:]) + s[0]
```

Can someone help me understand this?

Answer (score 2):

You are returning an append statement, which returns a None and not the list.

```
print(a.append('o'))
```

this will print a `None`

change your code to:

```
s = ["h", "e", "l", "l", "o"]
def reverse(s):
    if len(s) == 1:
        return s
    else:
        ret = reverse(s[1:])    # 'ret' needs to be returned
        ret.append(s[0])        # here 'ret' is updated but append returns a 'None'
        return ret              # returning the updated 'ret'
```

Answer (score 2):

In the first piece of code you are taking a list of strings, removing the first element and appending it in the end. Thus you are appending a string to a list, creating a None Type. The least change of code would be to cast the string to a list of string:

```
s = ["h", "e", "l", "l", "o"]
def reverse(s):
    if len(s) == 1:
        return s
    else:
        return reverse(s[1:]) + list(s[0])
```